# ジェネリッククラスをインスタンス化するときのパラメータを別のジェネリッククラスにすることは可能か？

Tags: java

Javaのジェネリック型についてなのですが、あるジェネリッククラスをインスタンス化したときに、そのジェネリッククラスのパラメータを、違うジェネリッククラスにすることは可能なのでしょうか？

Comment: サンプルコードを追記して質問内容をより具体的にして頂くことは可能ですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 問題の想定: 例えば、次のようなケースなのかなと思っています。

```
List<Number> l = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
// 以下をやりたいけどエラーになる！！
List<Integer> ints = (List<Integer>) l;
```

#### まず: 最悪キャストすれば動く

確実に問題を起こさないとわかっていて、コードを通すことが目的ならば、例えば次のようにできます。(warning が出ますが、 warning はアノテーションなどで抑制をやろうと思えばできる)

```
List<Number> l = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
List asRaw = (List) l;
List<Integer> ints = (List<Integer>) asRaw;
```

#### ただ、実際には

ただ、これをやってしまうと、「ジェネリック型の型安全性」を放棄してしまうことになるので、以下のように、ジェネリックとして取り扱いながらなおすのがよいのでは、と思っています。

直し方例:
  1. そもそも `List<Integer>` を利用するようにする。
  2. 新しい `List<Integer>` を作成し、元リストから中身を一つずつ取り出し、 instanceof で Integer にキャスト可能かどうかを判断しながら、新しい方に詰めなおす.

もしくは、ジェネリックメソッド・クラスの定義の仕方の問題かもしれないので、今実際に詰まっているコードを追記いただくと、より適切な回答を記載できるようになるのではないか、と思っています。

Answer (score 1):

「ジェネリッククラスのパラメータを、違うジェネリッククラスにする」というのが`new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>()`のようなことを指すのであれば、このように書けば可能です。